# Use UserForm ListBox to Populate Individual Cells in a Specified Range

Tags: excel, vba

My goal is to use a userform listbox and command button to populate data in cells one by one within a specified range of cells. Courtesy of this [ExcelVbals YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7fVLbCRyXEI), I have come up with the following code for my command button:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

myVar = ""

For x = 0 To Me.lbxTitle.ListCount - 1
    If Me.lbxTitle.Selected(x) Then
        If myVar = "" Then
            myVar = Me.lbxTitle.List(x, 0)
        Else
            myVar = myVar & " " & Me.lbxTitle.List(x, 0)
        End If
    End If Next x

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Range("C7:C73") = myVar

End Sub

Private Sub lbxTitle_Click()

End Sub
```

The problem is this code populates the entire "C7:C73" range, when I want to populate cells individually within that range using distinct values selected from the listbox.

Thank you for your time and consideration!

Comment: How will you know which value in the listbox to assign to which cell?

Comment: Instead of passing your values into `myVar` why not just put them right on the sheet? Although to the point above, it's not clear how you are indexing this.... i'd add more info to your question. Show the final value of `myVar` and how you want that value to be parsed and added to your cells. (Sample data, not the full 70 rows of data)

Comment: @PeterT I will select the values from the listbox manually for each cell within the range. Alternatively, I also thought it would be useful to populate data using values in the listbox for any cell I have selected. Basically I'm trying to save myself the pain of text intensive data entry by recycling common words and phrases.